# Hilarious Harry Potter fanfic: Snape disguises himself as a woman when taking baby Harry outside

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, severus-snape, fan-fiction

Most likely read on FanFiction.net, Draco and Harry are both de-aged into babies and Professor Snape becomes the unwilling guardian of them where hilarity ensues; the storytelling of this fic wasn't serious at all.

At some point, little Draco Malfoy demands chocolate which Snape denies him, at which point Lucius comes to visit the school after hearing about the news, affrontedly saying something along the lines of "I can't believe you denied my little angel chocolate!"

The two men decide to go out on an excursion into town, but can't risk being noticed, so Lucius decides they should dress-up as women while pushing the babies in their prams.

Snape has decided life as a woman sucks, as Lucius is going by "Lucy" even orders a salad for him when they stop at a cafe. It gets worse when Remus, who is somehow in town, becomes entranced by the disguised Snape and even tries to flirt with him not knowing who he is. Snape books it back to Hogwarts.

I know there's a possibility the fic may have been deleted since I bet even the author was ashamed of their own creation at some point, but I remembered reading this during a really low time in my life and scrolling through that ridiculous fic made me cry with laughter.

Comment: There are much weirder fics still up so this one might not be deleted either don't worry

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (Fanfic) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11922/how-to-ask-a-good-fanfic-story-id-question)